# BigQuery Value Splitting

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to separate/extract the log data into columns.
I tried to use the 'space' as the separator but there are spaces between the value too.
I have also tried to use regular expression but having difficulty because of the 'space' in the value.

As it is a log data with different key & value, I want to avoid hard-coding the key, ie: rt, shost, src...

Part of the sample data:

```
rt=Aug 19 2021 00:00:02 UTC+00:00 shost=dns.google src=8.8.8.8
```

BigQuery script to split the data, so I can use SAFE_OFFSET to get the array:

> SELECT split(details, ' ') FROM (SELECT 'rt=Aug 19 2021 00:00:02 UTC+00:00 shost=dns.google src=8.8.8.8' details)

BigQuery script regexp_extract:

> SELECT regexp_extract_all(details, r'[\w=.:]*') FROM (SELECT 'rt=Aug 19 2021 00:00:02 UTC+00:00 shost=dns.google src=8.8.8.8' details)

I couldn't think of any other way to solve this and will be happy to accept any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about marking the new log parameter with a special character? And then split at these. Since I do not know your data inputs, the special character is here `@<*>@`, something which should not be in any logs.

```
SELECT
  split(REGEXP_replace(details, r' (\w*=)',r'@<*>@\1'),'@<*>@')
FROM (
  SELECT
    'rt=Aug 19 2021 00:00:02 UTC+00:00 shost=dns.google src=8.8.8.8' details)
```